# " Call to undefinded function language_attributes() "

Tags: wordpress, dreamweaver

newbe coder - 
Setting up DW to customize wordpress on Local host. 
Everything seemed to be fine. 
Loaded header.php file, used "Live View" and got:

> Call to undefinded function language_attributes()
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\filename\header.php on line 12

Searched everywhere but cannot find answer.

There is no php closing tag in my header.php file. I've read somewhere there does not need to be one. Is this correct?
I tried putting a closing tag, but no success.

Comment: I also got this when I pulled up my page.php file.                                                "  Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header() in C:\xampp\htdocs\dw_wp\wp-content\themes\twentyfifteen\page.php on line 14  "

Comment: You're getting these errors since WordPress core has not been loaded. You can't run `header.php` directly, since that file depends on many other PHP files to work properly.